# SSIS 2012: Metadata out of sync after add/remove script parameter

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssis-2012

We have deployed several changes to SSIS packages successfully, but this particular change gives us an error of

> The component metedata is out of sync with the compiled script. Recompile the script using the Script Component Editor.

It runs fine in the debugger on my jump host. What do I do to "recompile the script"? Or is there a deeper problem?

**UPDATE 1:** This particular script component is more like a destination, and asynchronous. It accepts input rows, and all (or most) of them are consumed within the script (it updates external data via a Web Service), and only the error cases continue through to the output.

I have narrowed down the problem to the absolute minimum change that gives this error: adding another input column (or **remove** an unused input column). To be precise, after opening the package in Visual Studio 2012 on my jump host, double-click the *Perform ETL* task to open the Data Flow, then double-click the *G9 Web Service Script Component*.

[image: Screenshot of Script Component properties]

I switch to *Input Columns* - there are 16 ticked/listed - and I untick one that is actually not used in the script. Or I tick (add) another column (which I want to use in the script).

Then I swap back to *Script*, click on **Edit Script**, and wait for the VstaProjects window to come up.

I either close this VstaProjects window straight away, or I make an extremely minor change to the script (comment only), then Build > Build ScriptComponent_5aa...acb, then press the floppy (Save) symbol, then exit Vsta.

Then I run in the debugger (press green start arrow) and it runs as expected. I build by right-clicking the project (G9) and selecting *Build* (this might be redundant after running in debugger).

In Windows (File) Explorer, I navigate to the `G9/bin/Development` folder, double-click `G9.ispac` (steps through deploy: Project Development file; my-dev-svr; SSISDB > ACME-SSIS (which gives `SSISDB/ACME-SSIS/G9`); Deploy!

**Problem:** When I log into my-dev-svr, drill into Integration Services Catalogs, and run the package, then drill into the Overview Report (for this execution) > View Messages, I see several errors. The most important are

> 1. Perform ETL:Error: "G9 Web Service Script Component" failed validation and returned validation status "VS_ISBROKEN".
> 2. Perform ETL:Error: The component metedata is out of sync with the compiled script. Recompile the script using the Script Component Editor.

### Command Line

I'm not entirely convinced this is related, but here it is: I've copied `G9.ispac` to my-dev-svr, then logged in there and on the command-line, executed dtexec. Bear in mind that this is the same server where [SSIS debugging does not work](/questions/41691217/ssis-2012-packages-runs-in-sql-agent-not-in-bids-or-cmd-line).

```
D:\ACME\Deploy\SSIS>dtexec /Project G9.ispac /Package ACMEPortal_ProjectProperties_G9.dtsx
Microsoft (R) SQL Server Execute Package Utility
Version 11.0.6020.0 for 64-bit
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
Started:  10:51:21 PM
Warning: 2017-04-17 22:51:21.74
   Code: 0xC0016016
   Source:  SSIS:Property
   Description: Failed to decrypt an encrypted XML node. Verify that the project was created by the same user. Project load will attempt to continue without the encrypted information.
End Warning
Warning: 2017-04-17 22:51:21.74
   Code: 0x800190FF
   Source:
   Description: Failed to decrypt sensitive data in project with a user key. You may not be the user who encrypted this project, or you are not using the same machine that was used to save the project. If the sensitive data is a parameter value, the value may be required to run the package on the Integration Services server.
End Warning
Progress: 2017-04-17 22:51:25.61
   Source: Get ETL Configuration
   Executing query "etl_GetGenericETLConfigForACME".: 100% complete
End Progress
Progress: 2017-04-17 22:51:25.64
   Source: Get G9 Web Service Connection Config Details
   Executing query "etl_GetG9WSConfigSettings".: 100% complete
End Progress
Progress: 2017-04-17 22:51:25.65
   Source: Audit ETL Initiation
   Executing query "dbo.etl_AuditInitiation".: 100% complete
End Progress
Warning: 2017-04-17 22:51:25.68
   Code: 0x80019002
   Source: OnError
   Description: SSIS Warning Code DTS_W_MAXIMUMERRORCOUNTREACHED.  The Execution method succeeded, but the number of errors raised (6) reached the maximum allowed (1); resulting in failure. This occurs when the number of errors reaches the number specified in MaximumErrorCount. Change the MaximumErrorCount or fix the errors.
End Warning
Error: 2017-04-17 22:51:25.68
   Code: 0xC0010026
   Source: Set Propogate Error to False
   Description: The task has failed to load. The contact information for this task is "".
End Error
Error: 2017-04-17 22:51:25.71
   Code: 0xC0024107
   Source: Set Propogate Error to False
   Description: There were errors during task validation.
End Error
Error: 2017-04-17 22:51:25.71
   Code: 0xC0010026
   Source: Set FilenamePart and Error Variables
   Description: The task has failed to load. The contact information for this task is "".
End Error
Warning: 2017-04-17 22:51:25.72
   Code: 0x80019002
   Source: OnError
   Description: SSIS Warning Code DTS_W_MAXIMUMERRORCOUNTREACHED.  The Execution method succeeded, but the number of errors raised (10) reached the maximum allowed (1); resulting in failure. This occurs when the number of errors reaches the number specified in MaximumErrorCount. Change the MaximumErrorCount or fix the errors.
End Warning
Error: 2017-04-17 22:51:25.72
   Code: 0xC0010026
   Source: Set Propogate Error to False
   Description: The task has failed to load. The contact information for this task is "".
End Error
Error: 2017-04-17 22:51:25.73
   Code: 0xC0024107
   Source: Set Propogate Error to False
   Description: There were errors during task validation.
End Error
Error: 2017-04-17 22:51:25.73
   Code: 0xC0024107
   Source: Set FilenamePart and Error Variables
   Description: There were errors during task validation.
End Error
Warning: 2017-04-17 22:51:25.74
   Code: 0x80019002
   Source: ACMEPortal_ProjectProperties_G9
   Description: SSIS Warning Code DTS_W_MAXIMUMERRORCOUNTREACHED.  The Execution method succeeded, but the number of errors raised (8) reached the maximum allowed (1); resulting in failure. This occurs when the number of errors reaches the number specified in MaximumErrorCount. Change the MaximumErrorCount or fix the errors.
End Warning
DTExec: The package execution returned DTSER_FAILURE (1).
Started:  10:51:21 PM
Finished: 10:51:25 PM
Elapsed:  4.344 seconds
```

**UPDATE 2:** An excerpt from the Script Component.

```vb
' Microsoft SQL Server Integration Services user script component
' This is your new script component in Microsoft Visual Basic .NET
' ScriptMain is the entrypoint class for script components

Imports System
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Math
Imports Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.Wrapper
Imports Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Wrapper
Imports ScriptComponentTaskUtility.ACME_ETLDataFlowScriptComponentTasks '-- custom toolkit
Imports ScriptComponentTaskUtility
Imports Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts
Imports System.Windows.Forms

<Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.SSISScriptComponentEntryPointAttribute> _
<CLSCompliant(False)> _
Public Class ScriptMain
    Inherits UserComponent

    Private _updateLimit As Integer

    Private _rowCount As Integer

    Public Overrides Sub PreExecute()
        MyBase.PreExecute()
        '  
        ' Our application code follows 
        _updateLimit = 2   '-- Intending to replace this hard-coding
        _rowCount = 0
    End Sub

    Public Overrides Sub G9ProjectInput_ProcessInputRow(ByVal Row As G9ProjectInputBuffer)

        Try
            ' We limit the updated records to X per run (X = 2, but want to make configurable).
            ' Next ETL run will pick up next X
            _rowCount += 1
            If (_updateLimit > 0 And _rowCount > _updateLimit) Then Exit Sub

            Dim taskComponent As G9Project = New G9Project(Me.UserID, Me.Password, Me.Config, Me.WSURL)
            Dim readResponse As Project_DoReadResponse
            ''MessageBox.Show(Me.WSURL)
            readResponse = taskComponent.ReadProject(Row.g9ProjectNumber, Row.Planet)


            If (readResponse.Errors.Items.Length > 0) Then
                CreateErrorRows(Row, readResponse.Errors.Items(0).ShortDescription)
                Exit Sub
            End If
            Dim g9Project As Project = readResponse.Project

            '**********************************
            'Change the property values here
            Try


                ' Who's in charge? The Manager or Owner?
                If Not (Row.acmeInChargeCode_IsNull) Then
                    g9Project.SelectionCodes(10).Value = Row.acmeInChargeCode.ToString
                End If

                ' ... other fields

            Catch ex As Exception
                Row.ErrorColumnName = "Web Service Error"
                CreateErrorRows(Row, ex.Message)
                Exit Sub
            End Try

            'End of change of property values
            '**********************************

            Dim updateResponse As ResponseBase
            updateResponse = taskComponent.UpdateProject(g9Project)
            If (updateResponse.Errors.Items.Length > 0) Then
                CreateErrorRows(Row, updateResponse.Errors.Items(0).ShortDescription)
                Exit Sub
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            CreateErrorRows(Row, ex.Message)
            Exit Sub
        End Try
    End Sub

' #Region ************************ NOTE: Copy & paste following code block *********************
' contains private member variables, etc, including CreateErrorRows()

End Class
```

Comment: just open by `Edit the script`, and save, then press ok, the script will be re-compiled again.

Comment: @LONG, I've tried various things with *Edit Script*, and I've specifically tried your suggestion just then, with the same result.

Comment: check my answer in few minutes :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have already work out the script and make sure the script works fine. Then it has a lot chance it has issues in your `destination`. It seems that you are using the `Script component` as data source, try to check the `Metadata` from the output of the source (right click the precedence constraint), check them whether they are matched with the input of destination, more important, if you have made any changes to the source columns, you'd better to delete and create a new destination, sometimes it might cache the columns that no longer exists.

Comment: Hmm. The script is more like a destination. It is (or should be) asynchronous. In normal operation, it accepts input rows, but produces no output rows, because they are consumed (updating external data via Web Service call). Only the errors come to the output. Clarifying question now.

Comment: could you add breakpoint to that as `pre execution` what is your approach to do with the web service? did you assign the json to variables?

Comment: I'll have to call it a day ... it 01:13 (Australia/Melbourne) :-S ... I'll be back in about 9 hours. Other than to say everything works perfectly in the debugger. But not after deploy to the Test Server (`my-dev-svr`).

Comment: PreExecution breakpoint: On my jump host, the breakpoint is hit once, as expected. I continue, and it completes successfully. On `my-dev-svr` debugging doesn't work at all (as earlier advised/asked).

Comment: "*did you assign json to variables*": I don't understand that question, but I've put a script excerpt into the question. Does that answer the question, or the *approach with web service* question?

Comment: Checking the Metadata: I've looked at the metadata on both the input and output side of the Script Component (right-click arrow, choose Edit > Metadata) and all is as expected. There's a large number of columns (38 input, 38+2 output), but in the script component itself (Script Transformation Editor > Input Columns) only 16 columns are ticked/read-only. Untick one of those (it was unused in the script), or tick an extra one, and the *deployed* version stops working.

Comment: that might be the reason cause the issue. You need to `add columns` for `input` from your scripts.

Comment: This part *"more important, if you have made any changes to the source columns, you'd better to delete and create a new destination, sometimes it might cache the columns that no longer exists."* gave me the essential clue to solve the problem. I will elaborate in my own answer.

Answer (score 4):

It was necessary to record all the details/configuration/code of the Script Component, then to delete it and recreate it afresh. Then join up the flows again (for the input and output).

In this case, the script is a *Transformation* script, but in moral terms, it is a destination; only error cases come through to the output.

There was a second Script Component that also had to change as part of the same bug fix. Adding extra columns for input triggered the error there as well, so it was also necessary to do the same delete-and-recreate on this. It was also a *Transformation* script, but this is fully synchronous (every input row come through to output, with some read-write input columns changed, and some other read-only input columns copied/filtered to additional output columns).

It's important to note (prior to the delete-and-recreate), that I could always run it in the Visual Studio 2012 debugger on my jump host, but the "out of sync" error occurred after I had deployed the `G9.ispac` file to `my-dev-svr` (and running either via SSMS > Integration Services Catalog > ... package, or by SQL Server Agent > Job Activity Monitor > job).

An additional observation, that **after** the delete-and-recreate, I can now freely add and delete input columns to the script - the very activity that caused the error prior. After doing the input column changes, it is enough to press **Edit Script...**, wait for the VstaProjects window to appear, close it immediately, press OK on the *Script Transformation Editor* dialog, and verify that a red X does not appear.

I guess it's the SSIS equivalent of "Have you turned it off and turned it on again?"

Comment: `wait for the VstaProjects window to appear, close it immediately, press OK on the Script Transformation Editor dialog` ... this solves my issue